# process_request() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given) - Django Basic HTTP Auth Decorator

Tags: python, django

I was tasked with creating a basic decorator that we can decorate some specific django views with basic HTTP Authentication.

I have the following decorator:

```
def basic_auth(func):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.META.get("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"):
            encoded_auth =  request.META.get("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION")
            encoded_auth = encoded_auth[6:]
            auth = base64.b64decode(encoded_auth)
            auth_email = auth.split(":")[0]
            auth_password = auth.split(":")[1]
            if (auth_email == settings.BASIC_AUTH_EMAIL) and (auth_password == settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD):
                func()
            else:
                return HttpResponseForbidden("Forbidden")
    return process_request
```

I am using it to decorate a view like this:

```
@csrf_exempt
@basic_auth
def user_find(request):
    args = json.loads(request.body, object_hook=utils._datetime_decoder)
    providedEmail = args['providedEmail']
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=providedEmail)
        user_dict = {'exists': 'true', 'name': user.first_name, 'email': user.email}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(user_dict))
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        user_dict = {'exists': 'false'} 
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(user_dict))
```

For some reason I am not getting what I expect. The view works perfectly without the decorator but it will not with the decorator. I am getting the error above:

```
process_request() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Do you know what may be happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove self from **process_request** and pass **request** argument to **func()**

```
def basic_auth(func):

    def process_request(request):
        if request.META.get("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"):
            encoded_auth =  request.META.get("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION")
            encoded_auth = encoded_auth[6:]
            auth = base64.b64decode(encoded_auth)
            auth_email = auth.split(":")[0]
            auth_password = auth.split(":")[1]
            if (auth_email == settings.BASIC_AUTH_EMAIL) and (auth_password == settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD):
                func(request)
            else:
                return HttpResponseForbidden("Forbidden")
    return process_request
```

for better understanding of function decorator: 
http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing **request** as an argument to **func()**. Try with this:

```
if (auth_email == settings.BASIC_AUTH_EMAIL) and (auth_password == settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD):
    func(request)
else:
    return HttpResponseForbidden("Forbidden")
```